# Why would VirtualBox open when executing `vagrant up` instead of remaining headless?

Tags: vagrant, roots-sage, roots-toolkit

I build WordPress websites with [Roots](https://roots.io/) which creates a VirtualBox and configures it with Vagrant. One of the sites, when I execute `vagrant up` causes VirtualBox (Mac) to open and remain open. While all other projects do not.

Before I sift through the Roots codebase I was wondering if anyone knows any reasons this would occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirtualBox will open if you request the GUI to be opened. You'll have something like below in your Vagrantfile:

```
...
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
  ...
  vb.gui = true
  ...
end
...
```

You can refer to the [documentation].(https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/configuration.html#gui-vs-headless)